# Ansible Loops in query Module

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-template

Hi I have a requirement to read the content of all the files of specific directory and pass the
content to a variable.

```
- name: Generate  logs
  hosts: appserver
  vars:
    logs_dir: /properties
    logs: {}
  tasks:
    - name: Read log config files
      set_fact:
        log_files: "{{ lookup('fileglob', logs_dir + '/*.properties')|split(',') }}"
    - name: check values   
      debug:
        var: log_files
      
    - name: Generate  list
      set_fact:
         logs: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ query('file', log_files[1], wantlist=True) }}"
```

It is working when I am passing only one file I want to pass file by file to query module ? any suggestion and these are yaml files and please do let me help in fetching specific tags from file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: ***"Read all (yaml) files of specific directory and pass the content to a variable."***

A: There are more options. For example, given the tree for testing

```bash
shell> tree /tmp/properties
/tmp/properties
├── 01.properties
├── 02.properties
└── 03.properties

0 directories, 3 files

shell> cat /tmp/properties/01.properties 
var_01: '01'

shell> cat /tmp/properties/02.properties 
var_02: '02'

shell> cat /tmp/properties/03.properties 
var_03: '03'
```

---

1. Include the variables from all files and combine a dictionary. The play

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    log_dir: /tmp/properties
    log_files_glob: "{{ log_dir }}/*.properties"
    log_files: "{{ query('fileglob', log_files_glob) }}"
    log_files_dict: "{{ lookup('vars', *q('varnames', 'log_file_\\d+'))|combine }}"

  tasks:

    - block:
        - debug:
            var: log_files
        - include_vars:
            file: "{{ item }}"
            name: "log_file_{{ ansible_loop.index }}"
          loop: "{{ log_files }}"
          loop_control:
            extended: true
        - debug:
            var: log_files_dict
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  log_files_dict:
    var_01: '01'
    var_02: '02'
    var_03: '03'
```

---

2. You can simplify the code and read the standalone variables

```yaml
        - include_vars: "{{ item }}"
          loop: "{{ log_files }}"
        - debug:
            msg: |
              var_01: {{ var_01 }}
              var_02: {{ var_02 }}
              var_03: {{ var_03 }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    var_01: 01
    var_02: 02
    var_03: 03
```

---

3. The next option is using the module [*assemble*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assemble_module.html#ansible-builtin-assemble-module-assemble-configuration-files-from-fragments)

```yaml
        - assemble:
            src: "{{ log_dir }}"
            regexp: '.*\.properties'
            dest: /tmp/properties.yml
```

gives the file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/properties.yml
var_01: '01'
var_02: '02'
var_03: '03'
```

Include this file as you like.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    log_dir: /tmp/properties

  tasks:

    - block:
        - assemble:
            src: "{{ log_dir }}"
            regexp: '.*\.properties'
            dest: /tmp/properties.yml
        - include_vars:
            file: /tmp/properties.yml
            name: log_files_dict
        - debug:
            var: log_files_dict
      run_once: true
```

---

Q: ***"The data comes with backslashes like \"test\":\"somedata\",***

A: You'll get escaped quotes `\"` if you quote a JSON string. For example, the value of the variable *var1* below is neither YAML nor JSON. Because of the wrapping single quotes `'` it is a string.

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/properties/01.properties 
var_01: '{"test": "somedata", "config": {"somedata": "somedata"}}'
```

The play gives (in JSON)

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
    "log_files_dict": {
        "var_01": "{\"test\": \"somedata\", \"config\": {\"somedata\": \"somedata\"}}",
        "var_02": "02",
        "var_03": "03"
    }
```

In YAML, the single quotes `'` can be used. As a result, the double quotes `"` don't have to be escaped

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
  log_files_dict:
    var_01: '{"test": "somedata", "config": {"somedata": "somedata"}}'
    var_02: '02'
    var_03: '03'
```

When you remove the wrapping quotes the value will be a valid JSON (and valid YAML as well because JSON is a subset of YAML).

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/properties/01.properties 
var_01: {"test": "somedata", "config": {"somedata": "somedata"}}
```

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
    "log_files_dict": {
        "var_01": {
            "config": {
                "somedata": "somedata"
            },
            "test": "somedata"
        },
        "var_02": "02",
        "var_03": "03"
    }
```

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
  log_files_dict:
    var_01:
      config:
        somedata: somedata
      test: somedata
    var_02: '02'
    var_03: '03'
```

Comment: Its working thanks!!, But there is an issue in data when the data is copied to variable it comes with backslashes like \"test\":\"somedata\",\"config\":{ \"somedata\": \"somedata \" ,I dont need these I have tried with regex_replace but no help

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Ok got it , Actually the single quotes are not there as those properties files which I am supposed to read are created via ansible templates and I need to create a list of all the content inside it,I mean a list of dictionaries which contains the data of properties file.